# Using an Excel UDF inside another UDF

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

Is is possible to use one UDF inside another?

For example Columns A,B,C,D.

UDF1(w,x) - Calculates the product of the maximum of A and the Maximum of B
UDF2(y,z) - Calculates the product of the maximum of C and maximum of D

UDF1 and UDF2 work fine.

UDF3 to calculate the product of UDF1 and UDF2 (as in cell calc is trivial)

Can I make UDF3 that take the as input (w,x,y,z) and then passes w,x to UDF1 and y,z to UDF2 - return the answers from UDF1 and UDF2 and calculate the product?

(I know there are other ways to do what I am describing - its the concept I am interested in) --

Background:
I am trying to work up examples of programming inside Excel that starts by building simple UDFs and then recycling them (kinda like subroutines)  -- again, I appreciate that there are better ways of doing this.

Cheers
G

Comment: oops@pnuts: Just saw your comment :(

Comment: Um, why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I make UDF3 that take the as input (w,x,y,z) and then passes w,x to UDF1 and y,z to UDF2 - return the answers from UDF1 and UDF2 and calculate the product?

Yes.

Here is an example. Paste this in a module. I am using `SUM` for demonstration.

```
Function MainF(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, _
rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range) As Long
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    x = a(rng1, rng2)
    y = b(rng3, rng4)

    MainF = x + y
End Function

Function a(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Long
    a = rng1.Value + rng2.Value
End Function

Function b(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Long
    b = rng1.Value + rng2.Value
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: @pnuts: One should add [excel-vba] if working from Excel-VBA. [excel-vba-mac] is added when user wants to specify that he or she is working with mac else there is no need.

Comment: @pnuts - succinct and to the point.

Works a treat - and aardvark123 - total mental block on where to start.  Needed a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks
G